# Process memory usage output

Tags: python, linux, memory-management, process

I am wondering how to get the resident memory usage of a process in MB in all cases. Sometimes I get it in MB however other times it comes in GB.

I did look around for a solution however most of them did not work. Something that can be worked into `top -b -n 1 | grep %i | awk '{print$9}'` would be great.

Comment: Well there is no code at this time for what I want to do but I use top -b -n 1 | grep %i | awk '{print$9}' to find the CPU percent of a process.

Comment: Then why is this tagged as a python question then?

Comment: Well it is going into a python application. I can remove the tag if you do not think it is correct

Comment: @icebox3d If all you need is run this command, look at the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) package.

Comment: 'ps aux | awk '{print $6/1024}'' If you want in MB. This will print RSS of a process. If want process name also print last field with awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid using subrocess you can look at the [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) library.

Here's an example if you're just looking for info on a single process:

```
import psutil

pid = 14551

def rss_MB(pid):
    proc = psutil.Process(pid)
    mem_bytes = proc.get_memory_info().rss
    return( float(mem_bytes)/1048576 )

mem_MB = rss_MB(pid)
print "pid: %d has an rss of %f MB" % (pid, mem_MB)
```

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
import subprocess

lines = subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-xacuww']).splitlines()
del lines[0] # skip the header
for p in lines:
    items = p.split()
    print "Process:", items[-1], " memory:", items[5], "kB"
```

This was written on FreeBSD, where the RSS size is reported in kB. Options for `ps` on Linux might be different, check the manual page.